# Xamarin forms map crash on navigation away from map

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.forms

I've made an app where I display a map. On the same page I also have a button. When the button is clicked I want to display a modal page to enter some data. It works except from Android, where the app crashes when I do the navigation. It's this issue https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/81768/launching-a-modal-over-a-page-containing-a-map-maps-ad-m-cannot-be-cast-to-android-view-viewgroup

So far I haven't found a solution that fixes the issue. I'm running latest XF 2.3.4.247 stable

best regards

Comment: So far I'm removing the map from its parent children collection and adding it back in during OnDisappearing and OnAppering. Not the most elegant solution, but works so far.

Comment: As I remember, this was the only option to fix this issue, we also had this problem and this is the solution we decided to use, hoping it will be fixed in another way later on